# getting a full name from database for user id and storing in session

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

basically i want to get full_name and store that into a  session variable

```
session_start();

$user_name= $_POST['name'];

$result=$this->db->query("SELECT full_name FROM tbl_admin_users WHERE `user_id`='".$user_name."'");

$_SESSION['user']= $result->row()->full_name;

echo $_SESSION('user');
```

Comment: `echo $_SESSION['user']`

Comment: Also you are comparing user_id to user_name. Maybe a mistake in your query?

Comment: watch out for your sql injection vulnerability

Comment: ```'; DROP TABLE tbl_admin_users; --``` aaaaaaand your users table is gone. I know it's been mentioned but really watch out for SQL injection.

Comment: Are you getting any results back? Can you tell what you get if you dump all of the variables?

Comment: @jd182 except for the fact that `;` doesn't work with mysql /php so its not actually possible to run a second query. but yes sql injection is dangerous

Comment: can you do a `var_dump($result);`  to verify you are getting results back from the database?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Thnks it worked